# SOAP UI- How to implement ws security through Groovy Script

Tags: soapui

I have the following Security headers defined in SOAP projrct

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-F8B0DB3A9767BBBAB514490975980761">
<wsse:Username>username1</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">IjHr1fYyWHUVXlOnCbKgk9fb18Q=</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">IwSmJsmxFA53rZjXDT2q8w==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2015-12-02T23:06:38.075Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

I am working on AlertSite Monitoring tool from Smart Bear and it still does not has the functionality of ready ws-security configurations defined at project level.

So i need a way to implement the ws-security thru Groovy script also looking for some directions on how to utilize the groovy script to populate the security headers

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You mean it does not have functionality of adding soap header for outgoing request like soapUI?

Comment: You may use xslt to transform the request with soap headers.